# Convert string from column to parameter in dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a dictionary table with 'Condition' column where I store conditions for particular customers. Table's name is CustomerConditions:

[image]

Then I created dynamic SQL where I want to use this Condition:

```
declare 
    @TableName as nvarchar(10),
    @FieldName as nvarchar(20),
    @CustName as Nvarchar(50),
    @Condition as NVARCHAR(MAX)

set @Condition = (SELECT o.Condition FROM CustomerConditions o WHERE o.Group = @CustName)

declare @strSQL as NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @strSQL = 

'DECLARE @FieldName as nvarchar(20),
        @CustName as nvarchar(50)

;WITH NewCTE AS (
                    SELECT Tab1.Group, '+@FieldName+'
                    FROM (
                    SELECT
                    '+@Condition+' AS Group,
                    '+@FieldName+'
                    FROM '+@TableName+' as c) as Tab1)
            
SELECT * FROM NewCTE'

EXEC(@strSQL)
```

The problem is that when I pass `@Condition` to dynamic SQL string from column 'Condition' does not become part of SQL syntax - it's passed as expression, in the result I got:

[image]

This is not what I want. I want this 'Case WHEN...' to become part of my SQL syntax.

On the other hand when I'm not using `@Condition` but pass 'CASE WHEN..' explicitly then everything works well (all declared parameters works well, all is good):

```
;WITH NewCTE AS (
                    SELECT Tab1.Group, '+@FieldName+'
                    FROM (
                    SELECT
                    CASE WHEN '+ @FieldName +' LIKE ''XY%'' OR '+ @FieldName +' LIKE ''XYZ%'' then '''+ @CustName +''' END AS Group,
                    '+@FieldName+'
                    FROM '+@TableName+' as c) as Tab1)
```

So how can I pass this 'Case when' condition into dynamic SQL using parameter?

Comment: Warning, this is **wide** open to injection. [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: @Muska, Your query is incorrect (I mean it has syntax errors)

Comment: Where are the values for `@FieldName`, `@TableName` and so on?

Comment: Those values are passed in stored procedure. I didn't wrapped up my qurey in procedure here, just wanted to show how it works inside.

Comment: @SrinikaPinnaduwage I see you deleted your post. I had a question. Why we ought to take paramteres inside in triple commas instead of single commas? I did it with single commas and query worked well (of course excepting Condition parameter, I tried without this parametere and qurey worked properly)

Comment: There was a bug in the answer and I made a change - please chk now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While agreeing with the issue of dynamic prone to injection attacks, and assuming some random values for your non initialized variables, here is how I approach

The trick is

```
SELECT @Condition = REPLACE(@Condition, '@FieldName', @FieldName )
SELECT @Condition = REPLACE(@Condition, '@CustName', @CustName )
```

**So the main Query will be**

```
declare 
    @TableName as nvarchar(10) = 'MyTbl',
    @FieldName as nvarchar(20) = 'FldName',
    @CustName as Nvarchar(50) = 'C1' ,
    @Condition as NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    
SELECT @Condition = (SELECT o.Condition FROM CustomerConditions o WHERE o.[Group] = @CustName)
SELECT @Condition = REPLACE(@Condition, '@FieldName', @FieldName )
SELECT @Condition = REPLACE(@Condition, '@CustName', @CustName )

declare @strSQL as NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @strSQL = 'DECLARE @FieldName as nvarchar(20),       
@CustName as nvarchar(50)
;WITH NewCTE AS (
                    SELECT Tab1.Group, '+@FieldName+'
                    FROM (
                   SELECT
                    '+@Condition+' 
                    '+@FieldName+'
                    FROM '+@TableName+' as c) as Tab1)
            
SELECT * FROM NewCTE'

Select(@strSQL)
```

First provide proper values to your variables and execute this.
Instead of executing the query, what I did was create the query to see whether it got created as you want.

To be certain, you can copy paste the outcome and execute that.
Then you can change the last line to `Execute ...`

Comment: Ok, looks tricky. I'll check it out tomorrow at work. So instead SET parameter we SELECT it? Could you explain me the difference in this case? Can I use SET istead? (I'm talking about this part: SELECT @Condition = (SELECT o.Condition FROM...)

Comment: Set and Select - no difference, its my preference

Comment: You can try it in a fiddle, Key change is the REPLACE function

Comment: I implemented your solution but got in response:
Incorrect syntax near '+'. Don't know why. When I double click on message it appoints SELECT @Condition = (SELECT o.Condition FROM CustomerConditions o WHERE o.[Group] = @CustName)

Comment: Or maybe is it sth wrong with 'CASE WHEN...' condition itself? Do I need '+' inside?

Comment: I noticed that it's not problem with replacing parameters in 'case when..' statement because parameters are passed correctly. The problem is still the same - 'CASE WHEN..' is treated as STRING, not as part of my SQL synthax so CASE WHEN is not executing at all. In every single row in the output I have this 'Case when...' statement repeated (as shown im my original post). Maybe here is the problem: '+@Condition+' AS Group. So how can I make this 'CASE WHEN..' statement to be part of SQL synthax?

Comment: Can you please provide with the table structure, data input and expected output, with minimum fields. Please don't paste images, as its hard for those who answer to type and test)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218026/discussion-between-muska-and-srinika-pinnaduwage).

Comment: @Muska, if the discussion resolved your issue - please mark this as answer